# char passed into function that receives char. yet char& is in error

Tags: c++

error: no match for call to ‘(std::_Mem_fn<void (CNC::CGUI::*)(float, char)>) (float, char&)’

```
void CGUI::null(float numP, char dir){}

void CGUI::Function()
{
    auto function_X_axis = std::mem_fn(&CGUI::null);
}

void Move_X_axis(float numP, char dir){}

void CGUI::Function2()
{
    function_X_axis = std::mem_fn(&CGUI::Move_X_axis);

    char sign = 'e';
    function_X_axis(1.0f, sign);
}
```

dir and sign, are both char, not char reference.
Where did the char reference come from?
I am not using templates.
i have searched for different parts of the error, but nothing close.

Comment: Don't you need to pass the object of `CGUI` as the first argument to `function_X_axis`? (Referring the example here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn)

Comment: BTW your code looks incomplete. Please make sure it's a [mre].

Comment: "I am not using templates." You are. `std::mem_fn` is one.

Comment: @kiner_shah, now that alagner answered, it is obvious that "this" was suppose to be the first argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably because the argument could be passed as lvalue reference to char.
Passing by value would be as good.

It doesn't really matter as your problem is lack of the `CGUI` object:

```cpp
#include <functional>

struct CGUI
{
    void null(float, char);
};



void CGUI::null(float numP, char dir){}

int main()
{
    CGUI gui;
    auto function_X_axis = std::mem_fn(&CGUI::null);
    char sign = 'e';
    function_X_axis(gui, 1.0f, sign);
}
```

Haven't you confused `mem_fn` with `bind` or lambda of some sort?

Comment: thank you. added "this" as first argument, worked.   i found mem_fn for function pointer. later, found little on bind